# how to write protect a USB drive in C#

Tags: c#

I need to write protect single USB drive write protected so that the data cannot be copied or even viewed.I want to lock a specific folder or if possible the complete USB memory from being copied or opened.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do that.  Perhaps what you want instead is a way to store encrypted data on a USB drive?

Comment: hii I have alllready encrypted the information but that isnt secure with a algorith they may be able to decode that.I have seen the autorun.inf file created by Panda USB Vaccine which is completely write protected and Unreadable (even in Linux) but Iam not sure how to do somethnig like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can't be viewed and copied, than what is the purpose of writing to it??

If you want to make sure that only authorized programs / users can view the data, then you need to somehow validate if a program is authorized or not, which means that you have to enable reading (and thus copying) of the USB drive.

The other option is to use a password protected USB device from  a company that produces them and ask them to put your data on it. Because as long as you intend to make password protection by yourself you will only end up with encrypted data/folder which will get decrypted if user enters correct password, which means that they will be able to copy (maybe not in a typical ctrl-C way, but using some different approaches) everything to computer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is **not possible**, however you can write some code that prevents the user from accessing USB drive on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Write protection prevents a user from writing so they can't change the contents.  Some devices have hardware switches but I'm not aware of any that have a programmable setting.

Password protection can prevent all access, reading and writing.  Some devices have programmable interfaces to set and clear passwords.  Theoretically it seems possible to use standard ATA commands to set passwords, but in practice I haven't seen any USB devices that obey those commands.  Some manufacturers provide password protection but I guess they do it in nonstandard ways.  You'll have to analyse their techniques and duplicate them in your own program.